# Prestashop - I get error when I use $this->_select in adminController

Tags: mysql, sql, controller, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

When I extends adminController, and define attributes to display in  $this->_select variable, Prestashop display this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ' a.store_name, a.id_product FROM `ps_selstock_product` a ' at
>   line 3
>
> ```
>       SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
>                   , 
>     a.store_name,
>     a.id_product          FROM `ps_selstock_product` a
>
>
>                   WHERE 1 
>
>                   ORDER BY a.`id_selstock_product` ASC LIMIT 0,50
> ```

My $this->_select variable contains:

```
$this->_select = '
        a.store_name,
        a.id_product';
```

I know the query should be like this one, deleting ',':

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS

    a.store_name,
    a.id_product          FROM `ps_selstock_product` a


                  WHERE 1 

                  ORDER BY a.`id_selstock_product` ASC LIMIT 0,50
```

But I don't know how to process because the query is built by prestashop I defined just the attributes to display

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this ?

`$this->_select = 'a.store_name,a.id_product';`

Answer (score 1):

### The first problem

First of all, are you sure that store_name exists in Database. By default, Prestashop doesn't provide a variable called `store_name`. Maybe your shop has been customized, so you will have to investigate about this possibility.

I've seen in the code that modules uses that code to get the store name:

```
shop.`name`
```

So the code should be something like this:

```
$this->_select = 'a.`id_product`, shop.`name` ';
```

### The second problem

Remember that you have been overwritting a query, so something could be placed after the code. You have to add a comma `,`at the end of your query if some variables are added by the controller. So, in some cases, you will to have to add it depending on the controller you overrides.

```
$this->_select = 'a.`id_product`, shop.`name` , ';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set:

```
$this->table = 'selstock_product';
```

Prestashop will look for a Key Column named `Id_{tablename}` , so, you need to rename your PK Field according to the prestashop sintax, That is: `Id_selstock_product`

greetings